# Trying to manipulate other cells based on dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-sheets

I'd like to manipulate other cells based on the selection from a dropdown menu. For example in cell A1 I have a dropdown with company A, B, C

I need a formula for cell B3 to change the data based on the selection in cell A1.

EX:

If cell A1 selects Company A, I'd like to take data from another tab in my sheet that gives me data for company A and place it into cell B3.
If cell A1 selects Company B, I'd like to take data from another tab in my sheet that gives me data for company B also inside B3.

Basically summarizing different data based on selection of my dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=if(A1="A",A!A1,if(A1="B",B!A1,C!A1))
```